# mySQL WHERE clause issue in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a page where it lets users to edit their information which is stored in the database. However i can't get the WHERE clause to work it just keeps coming up with entry not found. Any help would be great thanks.!

```
         <?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("peopletank") or die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'")

or             die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>=1){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $firstname= $row['firstname'];
    $secondname= $row['secondname'];
}
?>
<form action="update.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $id;?>">

Value1: <input type="text" name="value1" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>">
<br>
Value2: <input type="text" name="value2" value="<?php echo $secondname?>">
<input type="Submit" value="Change">
</form>
<?php
}else{
    echo 'No entry found. <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go back</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: your code provided does not show how `$id` is populated, which seems to be, um, pretty important for your question

Comment: where is the source for $id in line 1 ?

Comment: I think the single quotes around the $id are the problem. But as everyone as asked, how are you populating $id ?

Comment: i need to get the WHERE clause to work and the id is there so they edit there information and no one else's as in the database they all have different id's

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'");
```

Make sure your `$id` is populated correctly. Try checking the value first if the query still didn't showed up like this :

```
echo 'The id is : '.$id;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'");
```

If the `$id` is populated correctly but still return no result then run the query manually in your mysql database, probably there is no result for specified `$id`

And while populating data, no need to fetch `$id` while you just have same `$id` ini this query.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $id = $row['id']; /* << Remove this */
    $firstname= $row['firstname'];
    $secondname= $row['secondname'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I aint 100% sure if its one of these things:
1) Try ending the statements with ;

2) Numbers dont have to be between ''

3) Try putting names of columns between ``

4) use LIMIT 1 where you can (makes things faster but not important)

5) Always try to use a selecter (faster)

```
<? 
if ( $query = mysql_query("SELECT `firstname`,`secondname` FROM `users` WHERE (`id` = $id) LIMIT 1;"))
{
    if ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
    {
        $firstname = $r['firstname'];
        $secondname = $r['secondname'];
    }
}
?>
```